# viewController in other view controller

Tags: iphone

when i try to call  view controller view in to another view controller . that time there delegate method like viewWillAppear: does not call .

any Suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`viewWillAppear:` is only called by the framework when you use the built-in view controller transitions like `presentModalViewController:animated:` or `pushViewController:animated:`. In other cases, you have to call `viewWill/Did(Dis)Appear:` yourself.